# How to pass parameters to local Prettydiff.com

Tags: javascript, diff, jslint

I've downloaded a copy of PrettyDiff to embed in my own local application, so I can compare two AJAX loaded files that are in two variables.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to make prettydiff work. Here's how I try :

```
var example1 = getFile('exemple1.txt');
var example2 = getFile('exemple2.txt');
var output = prettydiff("/*prettydiff.com api.lang: 8, api.mode: diff, api.diffview: inline, api.source:example1, api.diff: example2 */");
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output[0];
```

All I get is "Error: Source sample is missing.".

I've also tried to make an "api" variable that I fill with the parameters, but that doesn't work either.

The documentation doesn't give any example on how to pass the parameters (options, source and diff texts).

Anyone knows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found out a way to get it working. I still don't know the fuss about the parameters as comments as specified in the docs, but you can create a js object and pass all your parameters :

```
var api = new Object();
api.mode = "diff";
api.diffview = "inline";
api.lang = 8;
api.source = example1;
api.diff = example2;
var output = prettydiff(api);
```

Comment: How do you get data into example1 and example2

Comment: Here's another example of usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822460/pretty-diff-usage/30648547#30648547

Answer (score 1):

You can use prettydiff option like this.

```
const prettydiff = require("prettydiff");
let options = prettydiff.options;
options.source = content_Old;
options.diff = content_New;
options.diff_format = "html";
options.lang = "script";
options.color = "white";
options.diff_space_ignore = false;
options.diff_view = "sidebyside";
options.lexer = "script";
options.sourcelabel = "Original File";
options.difflabel = "Updated File";
options.mode = "diff";
options.parse_format = "htmltable";
options.list_options = true;
options.crlf = false;
options.force_indent = true;
outputHtml = prettydiff();
```